# Change URL of a button based on user input

Tags: javascript

I found this code:

```js
<a id="reflectedlink" href="http://www.google.com/search">http://www.google.com/search</a>
<input id="searchterm"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var link= document.getElementById('reflectedlink');
    var input= document.getElementById('searchterm');
    input.onchange=input.onkeyup= function() {
        link.search= '?q='+encodeURIComponent(input.value);
        link.firstChild.data= link.href;
    };
</script>
```

Is there a way to modify it for a button? Rather than a text link, I want a button with a URL that can be dynamically changed based on user input.

Comment: button does nothing with URL. Do you mean form?

Comment: You can set `link.href` property..

Comment: You want the button click-event to take the input value and set it as the link?

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear but thanks for the feedback. I found a code the does exactly what I want. I posted it below.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all.  I found [below code](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?179619-Change-onclick-url-from-user-input) that does what I want. I'll test the above as well.

```js
function submitForm() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  if (name == "") {
    alert("Enter the ID#")
  } else {
    window.location = "http://somesite.com/DispForm.aspx?ID=" + name;
  }
}
```

```html
Enter the ID#:
<input id="name" type="text">
<input type="button" onclick="submitForm()" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Why are you doing it this way? This is essentially the same as using a form with `method="get"` and `action="http://somesite.com/DispForm.aspx"`.